# Local Lexicon Based "similar questions"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, related-questions

SO users are from around the world. That said, different regions have different idioms and expressions. This means that *various SO users may phrase questions differently*, causing the "Related Questions" box to be inaccurate or miss related questions. This also adversely affects the "Related" column in the sidebar.

Consider this a request that something be done, although I'm not sure exactly what, though. I was thinking of a "regional" or "local" lexicon setting which would be tied to each account, or perhaps a master list of interchangeable words so that the "Related" views are more accurate.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the purpose of identifying duplicates on the sites. People have an incredible ability to ask the same question while sharing none of the terminology - so we do what we must to identify when two or more people ask the same question. That way, the next time someone uses the same terminology as anyone past, an answer is more likely to be found. If it's new terminology, all it does is create a bigger net to catch more terms.

Regarding your specific suggestion, I'm not sure about the success it would have. Extra duplicates increase the visibility of our answers not just internally, but on external search engines. Comparatively, the lexicon would operate internally for specific users, limiting how much it actually stops. As well, how is a person to know that there even exists other terms for what they're looking for? Or, more appropriately, how could one person's lexicon stop someone else from asking the same permutation? This also has a trouble with people who do not have accounts, as they would not be able to support a lexicon.